# Macintosh application - do all icon sizes have to be supplied?

Tags: macos, icons

This [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/icons-and-images/app-icon/) lists mac applications' icon sizes, divided into "@1x" and "@2x". When I supply only the largest one (1024 x 1024 px - labeled as "App Store - 2x") the application builds OK and displays the icon in all relevant places, even at much smaller sizes just fine.

The only hard requirement I found so far is in https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev4b0ebb1bb
and states "If you distribute your app through the App Store, add the App Store icon [...] drag an icon to the App Store - 2x well in the AppIcon image set"

Therefore the obvious question comes: do I need to supply multiple images of all possible pixel sizes? And if not then which sizes are mandatory?

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions. No, there's no need to provide all of them, but it's a good practice and it shows that you care. Icon is displayed on many places where the size differs significantly (Finder list = small icon, Dock = big icon, Spotlight = medium, ...). Also you're asking for a possible rejection if the scaled icon looks ugly (not likely, but it's Apple). We're talking about 5 icons here (okay, 10 icons if we count @1 & @2). Just provide them. There are utilities that can generate them for you. See, opinionated comment.

Comment: "This question is likely to be answered with opinions" - a pity. I was hoping for some links to unambiguous factual information.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, wish there was a link that stayed updated with unambiguous, factual information on exactly what is required. I used a program in the past to quickly generate all required icons. Then the rules changed & the program wasn't as nice as it used to be.

Short answer is, "No, all the sizes are not required." As for which are mandatory, those are the ones you left out & Xcode yells at you, or Apple rejects you. As inefficient as that sounds, it just is what it is.